# Custom calendar conversion

Tags: php, date, type-conversion

For a personnal project, I need to convert in PHP dates from our metric system, to a custom one. (And of course in the reverse way too).

The custom date work like :

```
24h => 2H30
1 season/month (it's the same) => 135 days of 2h30
1 years => 4 seasons of 135 days of 2h30
The year 400 correspond to 03/26 OOhOO.
For exemple : 09:20 - 14 jun 2013 => 91 Oridor 407 - 01 h 03 m
```

What is the best way to do this conversion in the two ways.

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't understand your system. Can you elaborate?

Comment: A day in the custom system correspond to 2h30 in our.
There is 135 days in a month, a 4 month for a year.
The begining of the calendar is the year 400, the 26th of March 2013

Comment: What dates do your seasons run from/to?